# Heroku giving H10 error with npx create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I am creating a react app using npx create-react-app, however, no matter what I do, heroku gives me an H10 error back. Is there a way to get a more detailed error message? And how do I get the app up and running? Here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "DONTEXECUTEbuild": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.1"
  }
}
```

And this is my Procfile

```
web:npm start
```

**Edit 1:**

I tried running `heroku restart` and installing https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git buildpack.

**Edit 2:**
This is the error message I get:

```
2020-04-12T10:12:16.885382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-12T10:12:27.041455+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-12T10:12:27.041478+00:00 app[web.1]: > portfolio@0.1.0 start /app
2020-04-12T10:12:27.041478+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-04-12T10:12:27.041478+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-12T10:12:29.005933+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.174.102/
2020-04-12T10:12:29.006390+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-04-12T10:12:29.006491+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-04-12T10:12:29.006574+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-04-12T10:12:29.006803+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-04-12T10:12:29.006804+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-12T10:12:29.112722+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the version of React in package.json. I changed react version to 16.12.0,
react-dom to 16.12.0, react-router-dom to 5.1.2 and react scripts to 3.2.0.. It worked fine afterwards. Another option is to change create react app webpack config in heroku settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a detailed error log by first installing heroku cli globally:
[herokudownloadlink](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)

then use your command line to login into heroku:

```
heroku login
```

after providing your credentials. do :

```
heroku logs -tail -a <your application name>
```

You will now see a detailed log of what happened. A H10 error usually means the process ended with an error. It could be because maybe heroku could not bind to a port.

Also in your package.json change "DONTEXECUTEbuild" to "build". heroku needs to build sometimes for optimal performance.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to do `git push heroku master` after installing buildpack. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, after a lot of struggles it worked after downgrading react-scripts to 3.1.2 in package.json (before this I had same version as you)

"react-scripts": "3.1.2"

also removed node modules and then re-run npm install